# Macro evaluation inside \qrcode{...}

Tags: macros, qrcode

I have two macros. The first, `\qrwifidata`, generates a string from two arguments and some optional key value. The second, `\qrwifi`, takes the same arguments and generates a QR code with text overlay.

```
\newcommand{\qrwifidata}[3][]{\begingroup\setkeys{qrwifi}{#1}%
    WIFI:S:#2;T:\qw@enc;P:#3;;%
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\qrwifi}[3][]{\begingroup\setkeys{qrwifi}{#1}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node at (0, 0) {\qrcode{WIFI:S:#2;P:#3;T:\qw@enc;;}};%
        \node[fill=white,align=center] at (0, 0) {#2\\#3};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\endgroup}
```

Both work fine on their own. But now, I want to reuse the first macro inside the second as

```
\newcommand{\qrwifi}[3][]{\begingroup\setkeys{qrwifi}{#1}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node at (0, 0) {\qrcode{\qrwifidata[encryption=\qw@enc]{#2}{#3}}};%
        \node[fill=white,align=center] at (0, 0) {#2\\#3};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\endgroup}
```

However, using the latter version produces a lot of errors like 'Undefined control sequence' and 'Illegal parameter number'. I guess, this has to do with macro expansion order, so I tried inserting some `\expandafter`s, but to no avail.

How can I have `\qrwifidata` expanded first and its result passed to `\qrcode`?

For completeness, here is a minimal (non)working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keyval}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\qw@size}
\define@key{qrwifi}{size}{\setlength\qw@size{#1}}

\define@key{qrwifi}{encryption}{\def\qw@enc{#1}}

\setkeys{qrwifi}{
    encryption=WPA,
    size=5cm,
}

\newcommand{\qrwifidata}[3][]{\begingroup\setkeys{qrwifi}{#1}%
    WIFI:S:#2;T:\qw@enc;P:#3;;%
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\qrwifi}[3][]{\begingroup\setkeys{qrwifi}{#1}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node at (0, 0) {\qrcode[level=H,height=\qw@size,padding]{WIFI:S:#2;P:#3;T:\qw@enc;;}};%
%        \node at (0, 0) {\qrcode[level=H,height=\qw@size,padding]{\qrwifidata[encryption=\qw@enc]{#2}{#3}}};%
        \node[fill=white,align=center] at (0, 0) {#2\\#3};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\endgroup}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \qrwifidata[encryption=WEP]{SSID}{Key}

    \qrwifi[encryption=WEP]{SSID}{Key}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\qrcode` needs to see something that expands to the things to encode, not the whole set of instruction to produce them.

Comment: What would that be? I also tried `\def\qw@data{\qrwifidata[encryption=\qw@enc]{#2}{#3}}` and then `\qrcode{\qe@data}`. But this still produces the same errors.

Comment: Of course: they do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure why you pass again the option to `\qrwifidata`, which is *already* known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to evaluate again a key that's already set to the desired value.

Anyway, `\qrcode` expands its second argument, but key setting cannot appear there.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keyval}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\qw@size}
\define@key{qrwifi}{size}{\setlength\qw@size{#1}}
\define@key{qrwifi}{encryption}{\def\qw@enc{#1}}

\setkeys{qrwifi}{
  encryption=WPA,
  size=5cm,
}

\newcommand{\qrwifidata}[2]{%
  WIFI:S:#1;T:\qw@enc;P:#2;;%
}

\newcommand{\qrwifi}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
  \setkeys{qrwifi}{#1}%
    \node at (0, 0) {%
      \qrcode[level=H,height=\qw@size,padding]{\qrwifidata{#2}{#3}}%
  };
    \node[fill=white,align=center] at (0, 0) {#2\\#3};%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\qrwifi[encryption=WEP]{SSID}{Key}

\end{document}
```

[image]